# How to access assets with webpacker gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, vue.js, webpack-dev-server, webpacker

Could you explain me how to access assets from webpacker gem within vue.js components? For example - how to create div with background image. I've tried use /app/assets/images and /app/javascripts/assets folders but images is only available in template section, but not in style section :(

in my case

```
<template>
    <div id="home">
        <div id="intro">
            <img src="assets/cover-image-medium.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

works fine, but

```
<style scoped>
    #intro {
        height: 200px;
        background: url("assets/cover-image-medium.png");
    }
</style>
```

not working :(

Whats wrong?

Comment: Have you configured `vue-loader` to use `css-loader` to process template styles?

Comment: @bzeaman do you mean https://github.com/rails/webpacker#css-modules ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

New Rails' webpacker stuff is pretty raw, so that's the configuration that works for me:

config/webpacker.yml (for webpacker 3):

```
resolved_paths: ['app/javascript/images', 'app/javascript/src']
compile: false
# ...
```

JS files:

```
/app
  /javascript
    /packs
      # only entry point files
      vue_application.js
    /src
      some_component.vue
    /images
      logo.svg
```

in component:

```
<script>
import 'images/logo.svg'
</script>
```

in template:

```
<img src='~images/logo.svg' />
```

point the tilde here - it means that the image is a module dependency

in CSS:

```
<style lang='sass'>
#app
  background: url('../images/logo.svg')
</style>
```

For some reason tilde does not work here, so relative path is used.

Comment: Thank you @sandrew, your answer was really helpful

Comment: If I use `<img :src="pathFromComputedProp" />` and `pathFromComputedProp(){  return '~images/logo.svg' }` - this will not work. Also, it will not work if instead tilde I will use relative path: `pathFromComputedProp(){  return '../images/logo.svg' }`. Maybe there is way to fix it too?

Comment: Thank you!  (Why is this NOT in the webpacker documentation!?)

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly, you will have to find the `webpack.base.conf.js` file inside your `build` folder, then find the code that looks like this:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
  alias: {
    'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
    '@': resolve('src')
  }
}
```

Then add the following line to the `alias` object: `'assets': resolve('src/assets/')`, which will work for the `assets` folder being right below the `src` folder. You can also change the key string from `assets` to whatever alias name you desire.

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention, **to access aliases in style code, you have to prefix it with a `~` (telda) so that `assets` becomes `~assets`.**

Answer (score 3):

Since this is tagged with Vue.js I will answer for that. None of the other answers worked with Vue 2.x.

## For Attributes

A webpacker `require` statement returns the full URL of the required asset (resolved based on your `resolved_paths` inside `webpacker.yml`). Based on that, you can do something like this:

```html
<img :src="require('images/what-a-pain.png')" alt="Finally working" />
```

Please note the colon causing the `src` attribute to be bound to the result of the javascript expression.

You can also use ID anchors by appending them, for example with SVG:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <use :href="require('images/icons.svg') + '#copy'" />
</svg>
```

Vue templates are generally pre-compiled to javascript equivalents, so a `require` statement is needed to pull the assets in at compile time, not runtime.

## For CSS `urls`, scoped or not

Simply use a tilde `~` and a path. The path must be *relative* to either the file including it or the `resolved_paths` from `webpacker.yml`.

```css
.relative-pathed {
    background: url(~../../../assets/images/quitethepath.svg) center center no-repeat;
}
.works-after-editing-webpackeryml {
    background: url(~images/quitethepath.svg) center center no-repeat;
}
```

For this usage there is no need to `require()` the asset.

*Please note:* there is a difference in paths between development and production, especially if Sprockets is also used. Simply doing `src="/assets/image.png"` will sometimes work in developement, *but not production*.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
background: url("/assets/cover-image-medium.png");
```

Instead of

```
background: url("assets/cover-image-medium.png");
```

Comment: Doesn't work - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I did changes in development.rb related to static assets from this link, but still don't work. Here is log - https://pastebin.com/W1v73fLj As you may see - webpack is failed to compile

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed `sass-rails` gem, try this:

```
<style scoped>
#intro {
    height: 200px;
    background: image-url("cover-image-medium.png");
}
</style>
```

Comment: yep - I have it installed but your code doesn't work too :(